# How to get the events for second SD card insertion/removal on Raspberry Pi board in c++ in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, udev

Could anyone please tell me how to get the events for insertion/removal of second SD card in card reader connected to raspberrypi board.

when I connect empty card reader(without SD card) on raspberrypi board,udev is triggering the events.
when I insert one SD card on connected card reader, then also udev is triggering the events but when I insert second
SD card on the same card reader. I am not getting any events by udev/udev is not triggering any events for second SD card.

Could anyone please help me on this how to get events on second SD cards insertion/removal.

I gone through various post but didn't get any helpful answer.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific: what kind of events are you expecting? are they not delivered by the kernel e.g. to `udevadm monitor`?

Comment: Insertion and removal event of second SD card while inserting and removing.
But here  I am not at all getting any event from udevadm monitor while insertion and removal of second SD card from card reader which is connected to 
raspberrypi board. udevadm monitor is triggering only for first SD card.

So how to get the events while Inserting and removing  of second SD card.